# Setting up Unit Tests for WebRole cloud service project?

Tags: unit-testing, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to set up Unit Tests for my WebRole project. I created a separate project "MyWebRole.Tests". The issue I'm having is when I instantiate my controller methods they call on

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("GetValue");
```

The Unit Test project I created doesn't have any RoleEnvironment set up for it, therefore the Tests error out. And researching more into this it seems like here is no way to share configuration settings between multiple roles.

I would also not like to create a separate WebRole Project for my UnitTest as that would mean it would get deployed.

How can I write Unit Test for my Webrole so I have access to the

```
RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("GetValue");
```

And at the same time the code for the unit tests doesn't get deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this applying the External Configuration Store Cloud Pattern. You can read more about it in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store

If you want to keep with the current solution, you'll need an interface for RoleEnvironment and create a mock. I found this one:

https://searchcode.com/file/28014050/ServiceRuntime/Contracts/IRoleEnvironment.cs

you can give it a try.